# How do I make lsp-mode ignore a node_modules folder + others?

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp

I want to know how to make lsp-mode ignore a node_modules folder (along with say, folder asdf and temp). This is what I have:

`(setq lsp-file-watch-ignored (rx (or "node_modules" "asdf" "temp")))`

but for some reason it is not working. [This official link](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/performance/#ignore-watch-foldersfiles) says that lsp-mode uses a regex for lsp-file-watch-ignored, but the error I am getting seems to imply that it is expecting a list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `lsp-file-watch-ignored-directories`? Does it not work?

Comment: I'm trying `(add-to-list 'lsp-file-watch-ignored-directories "[/\\\\]\\.node_modules\\'")` and it's not working, probably cause my regex is bad or something